# What coin is this? Arabic: 10 Fulus, over crossed wheat and lead

Tags: identification, currency, money, numismatics

Years ago (maybe 15), my grandfather gave me this coin and I have no idea what it is or where it came from. Can anyone help? I'm pretty sure it came from the Middle East (he did a lot of work there for the US government way back when).[image: Picture of a coin]

Comment: Welcome! To me it looks more like an Indian coin and the search "Indian coin grain" brought up some similar designs. Then I tried the Google reverse image search and didn't  find anything either. I'm not sure if it is Indian, but the writing looks Indian and I found several Indian coins that looked similar. How does the other side look like? Maybe that gives more clues.

Comment: @MatthiasSchreiber The writing is not Indian, but Arabic, it's written "Al-Jomhoreeyah Al-'Eraqeeyah" (Iraq).

Answer (score 19):

According to [Jamila's Coins and Notes Collection blog](http://jamilacoinsandnotescollection.blogspot.de/), this is a modern iraqi coin from 1981. Here's a photo showing the front and back of that coin:

[image]

I've found it on [on Jamila's blog, with an overview of iraqi coins](http://jamilacoinsandnotescollection.blogspot.de/2010/11/iraq-coins-14.html). There, it's described as follows:

> IRAQ - 10 Fils (Year 1981) (AH 1401)
>
> Description: Under President:
>   Saddam Hussein (16 Jul 1979 - 09 Apr 2003)
>
> Obverse: Plantation of Date  Palms, Year of  English era on left and Arabic Era on right.
>
> Reverse:
>   10 Fulus (in arabic) above two leaves.
>
> Composition: Steel.
>   Edge: Plain.

See also [the detailed description on numista.com, including a translation of the arabic text](http://en.numista.com/catalogue/pieces4660.html).

Comment: Wow that's awesome! That's the exact coin. I actually remembered earlier today that he gave me three coins total (so you'll probably see another coin post or two from me within the month). Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: "English era" is really a funny way to put it.